# Scala - case match partial string

Tags: string, scala, pattern-matching

I have the following:

```
serv match {

    case "chat" => Chat_Server ! Relay_Message(serv)
    case _ => null

}
```

The problem is that sometimes I also pass an additional param on the end of the serv string, so:

```
var serv = "chat.message"
```

Is there a way I can match a part of the string so it still gets sent to Chat_Server?

Thanks for any help, much appreciated :)

Comment: As can be seen below, there are solutions. But maybe `serv` wants to be a more structured value and not just a simple `String`?

Comment: a `case class` would be perfect for this!

Comment: The use of `null` should be avoided in Scala; use `Option` instead. `null` really only exists for interoperability with Java.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use regular expressions, make sure you use a sequence wildcard like `_*`, e.g.:

```
val Pattern = "(chat.*)".r

serv match {
     case Pattern(_*) => "It's a chat"
     case _ => "Something else"
}
```

And with regexes you can even easily split parameter and base string:

```
val Pattern = "(chat)(.*)".r

serv match {
     case Pattern(chat, param) => "It's a %s with a %s".format(chat, param)
     case _ => "Something else"
}
```

Comment: in your case, the "chat" variable in the pattenr matching is clearly useless, you can replace it with `Pattern(_)`

Comment: @Nicolas yes, you're right. I've not ommited it cause in op version `chat` would be used as a message to server.

Comment: Beware, in your solution, `chat` variable will always be equal to `"chat"` if the pattern matched. (that's why I wrote that it was useless)

Comment: @Nicolas Oh, I've modified pattern. Now it will grab rest of the string too.

Comment: The regex will fail to match if there's a newline in the message part.

Comment: Thanks alot, went with your suggestion as I can easily access the extra param passed :)

Answer (score 55):

Have the pattern matching bind to a variable and use a *guard* to ensure the variable begins with "chat"

```
// msg is bound with the variable serv
serv match {
  case msg if msg.startsWith("chat") => Chat_Server ! Relay_Message(msg)
  case _ => null
}
```

Comment: It is so called *guard* in the first case expression

Comment: Kyle's answer is perfect and still relevant to modern scala. You could also use msg.contains("chat") if you want to match something like "message.chat". It's another way of guarding.  Thanks Kyle.

Comment: Please specify what is `msg` and what do you mean by "pattern matching bing to  a variable"

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to dismiss any groupings when using regexes, make sure you use a sequence wildcard like `_*` (as per [Scala's documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/util/matching/Regex.html)).

From the example above:

```
val Pattern = "(chat.*)".r

serv match {
     case Pattern(_*) => "It's a chat"
     case _ => "Something else"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Scala 2.13, you can use the `s` interpolator in a match

```
serv match {
  case s"chat" => ...
  case s"chat.$msg" => doSomething(msg)
  ...
}
```