# How to distinguish triple quotes from single quotes in macros?

Tags: scala, macros

I am writing a macro `m(expr: String)`, where `expr` is an expression in some language (not Scala):

```
m("SOME EXPRESSION")

m("""
  SOME EXPRESSION
""")
```

When I am parsing the expression I would like to report error messages with proper locations in the source file. To achieve this I should know the location of the string literal itself and the number of quotes of the literal (3 or 1). Unfortunately, I did not find any method that returns the number of quotes of the literal:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

object Temp {
  def m(s: String) : String = macro mImpl

  def mImpl(context: Context)(s: context.Expr[String]): context.universe.Tree = {
    import context.universe._

    s match {
      case l @ Literal(Constant(p: String)) =>
        if (l.<TRIPLE QUOTES>) {
          ...
        } else {
          ...
        }

      case _ =>
        context.abort(context.enclosingPosition, "The argument of m must be a string literal")
    }
  }
}
```

What should I put instead of `<TRIPLE QUOTES>`?

Comment: Have you tried matching `l` against a pattern with single qoutes and a pattern with triple qoutes? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770416/scala-case-match-partial-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way i can think of is to access the source file and check for triple quotes:

```
l.tree.pos.source.content.startsWith("\"\"\"",l.tree.pos.start)
```

You need also to edit your matching case:

```
case l @ Expr(Literal(Constant(p: String))) =>
```

Here the version with some explanation:

```
val tree: context.universe.Tree = l.tree
val pos: scala.reflect.api.Position = tree.pos
val source: scala.reflect.internal.util.SourceFile = pos.source
val content: Array[Char] = source.content
val start: Int = pos.start
val isTriple: Boolean = content.startsWith("\"\"\"",start)
```